# How to resize bar chart image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I show bar chart image with this code.

```
print(df['a'][1:].astype(int).plot.bar())
```

The image is very small I try to resize image by using matplotlib like this code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.plot(df['a'][1:].astype(int).sum())
```

when I run I show empty image without bar chart. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is empty is that your `df['a'][1:]`, is a 1d vector (a pd.Series). The sum of that, is a scalar. You cannot plot a scalar.

I think for a bar chart, you need `plt.bar(df['a'][1:])`.

As for the figure size, you have the figsize command, like you note in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give, even bigger integer parameters to the `figsize`

For instance:

`plt.figure(figsize=(18, 5))`

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5)) # set the size that you'd like (width, height)
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], label = 'first bar')
plt.bar([5,6,7,8], [0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1], label = 'second bar')
ax.legend(fontsize = 14)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

i would basically compute the data for x and y before. It seems that the plot is empty because it is only a scalar. The following code works:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,5,6]), columns=['x'])
df['y'] = df['x'][1:].astype(int).sum()

#Change your fig size here
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.bar(df.x, df.y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the size with `figsize`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5)) # set the size that you'd like (width, height)
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], label = 'first bar')
plt.bar([10,11,12,13], [0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1], label = 'second bar')
ax.legend(fontsize = 14)
```

[image]